# Shell script to terminate program but causes output file to not be written

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I am wanting to run a program in the background that collects some performance data and then run an application in the foreground. When the foreground application finishes it detects this and the closes the application in the background. The issue is that when the background application closes without first closing the file, I'm assuming, the output of the file remains empty. Is there a way to constantly write the output file so that if the background application unexpectedly closes the output is preserved?

Here is my shell script:

```
./background_application -o=output.csv &
background_pid=$!

./foreground_application
ps -a | grep foreground_application
if pgrep foreground_application > /dev/null
then
     result=1
else
     result=0
fi

while [ result -ne 0 ]
do
     if pgrep RPx > /dev/null
     then
          result=1
     else
          result=0
     fi
     sleep 10
done
kill $background_pid
echo "Finished"
```

I have access to the source code for the background application written in C++ it is a basic loop and runs fflush(outputfile) every loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This would be shorter:

```
./background_application -o=output.csv &
background_pid=$!
./foreground_application
cp output.csv output_last_look.csv
kill $background_pid
echo "Finished"
```

Comment: I only want to kill the background application if the foreground application also is closed. The output file remains empty unless the background application closes properly. I was wondering if there was a way to have the file written to always so if the background application does close the data isn't lost.

Comment: Modified answer to copy _output.csv_ to _output_last_look.csv_ just before killing the background application.  Please check if the resulting copy has the desired output data.  Note:  in the above code, the foreground application is in the _foreground_ -- therefore `kill` only happens _after_ the foreground app is closed.

Comment: when the background application is running it creates the output file but it is empty until the program closes properly. Thanks for your help, I'll try that shell script

Comment: Drat, the script wouldn't work in that case.  It seems like `background_application` is the problem then.  Is there _any_ way for it to close properly?

Comment: if you could send the x keystroke to the background application, maybe that should have been the original question

Comment: Please test if "x" can be sent through standard input:  `yes x | background_application`

Comment: Thanks for trying that didn't seem to work but I was able to correct the issue by changing the way the file is opened and making sure to flush the output every loop iteration.